# Get text value from <lightning:inputField> not working properly

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-inputfield

I would like to get the value from `lightning:inputField`. I want to be able to get the length of the string and ultimately create a keyup event for character length validation. However, I can't directly read the value from `lightning:inputField` and it seems that two way binding is not working?

**Component**

```
<aura:attribute name="longBusinessDescription" type="String" default="" />

<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="editForm" recordId="{!v.BusinessDetailId}" objectApiName="BusinessDetail__c">
    <lightning:button variant="brand" type="submit" name="save" label="Save" onclick="{!c.saveBusinessDetails}" class="slds-m-top_medium"/>
    <lightning:button variant="brand" name="save" label="Cancel" onclick="{!c.cancelBusinessDetails}" class="slds-m-top_medium"/>
    <lightning:inputField aura:id="LongBusinessDescription" fieldName="LongBusinessDescription__c" value="{!v.longBusinessDescription}"/>
    <div>
       {!v.counter}/500
    </div>
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

**Controller**

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {      
        helper.getBusinessDetailsFieldsHelper(component);           
    },    

    editBusinessDetails : function(component, event, helper) {      
        helper.editBusinessDetailsHelper(component);            
    },

        saveBusinessDetails : function(component, event, helper) {      
        helper.saveBusinessDetailsHelper(component);            
    },

    cancelBusinessDetails : function (component, event, helper)
    {
        helper.cancelBusinessDetailsHelper(component);
    }
})
```

**Helper**

```
getBusinessDetailsFieldsHelper : function(component)
{
    var planId = component.get("v.recordId");
    console.log(planId);

    var action = component.get("c.getBusinessDetailsFields");

    action.setParams({
        "planId" : planId
    });

    console.log('planId = ' + planId);

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
            console.log('state = ' + state);
            var data = JSON.parse(response.getReturnValue());

            component.set("v.BusinessDetailId", data["Id"]);
            component.set("v.longBusinessDescription", data["LongBusinessDescription__c"]);

    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},

editBusinessDetailsHelper : function(component)
{
    component.set("v.editMode", true);
    var longDescription = component.get("v.longBusinessDescription");

    component.set("v.counter", longDescription.length);

},

saveBusinessDetailsHelper : function(component)
{
    component.find("editForm").submit();

    component.set("v.editMode", false);
},

cancelBusinessDetailsHelper : function(component)
{
    component.set("v.editMode", false);
}
```

With the way the component is setup I get an ID from an outside apex class. I set the longBusinessDescription to the LongBusinessDescription__c field. If I use this attribute then the attribute does not update when my `lightning:inputField` is updated, the two way binding seems to not be working?

For example: LongBusinessDescription__c = "Initial Value"

when I load the page the `lightning:inputField` will display "Initial Value".

When I hit the edit button the `lightning:inputField` will display whatever value is in longBusinessDescription which happens to be "Initial Value".

After I edit the desciption to "Initial Value + New Value" and hit save, the database will update but longBusinessDescription will not. This means that if I try to edit the page before refreshing it will display the old "Initial Value."

Finally, what this all means is that if I try to create a keyup event to listen for any key presses in the `lightning:inputField` the aura attribute does not update, which means I have no way of checking the value of the `lightning:inputField` on a key press.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to have an unnecessary amount of detail. See if this solves your problem:

> COMPONENT:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName">

    <aura:attribute name="characterCount" type="Integer"/>

    <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="editForm" recordId="{!v.recordId}" objectApiName="{!v.sObjectName}">
        <lightning:inputField aura:id="longBusinessDescription" fieldName="Name" value="Prepopulate here" onchange="{!c.validateLength}"/>
        <div>
            # of characters entered = {!v.characterCount}
        </div>
    </lightning:recordEditForm>

</aura:component>
```

> CONTROLLER JS:

```
({
    validateLength : function(component, event, helper) {
        var longBusinessDescription = component.find("longBusinessDescription").get("v.value");
        var characterCount = longBusinessDescription.length;
        component.set("v.characterCount", characterCount);
        if(characterCount > 100)
            alert('Too many characters entered!');
    }
})
```

**In short**: lightning:inputField doesn't support keyup event (yet), but there is `onchange` as [mentioned here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:inputField/specification). Plus, if you would like to get the value of any lightning element that is assigned an aura:id (and supports the value param), you need to do: `component.find("myAuraIdHere").get("v.value")`